# Outlook web add-ins grayed out in delegate calendar in Outlook Desktop app

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Outlook web add-ins are showing grayed out in a delegate calendar in Outlook Desktop app on appointments/meetings windows. By delegate calendar I mean a calendar shared with me by another person in the company, with full permissions on share - so I can create/edit meetings/appointments from his calendar from my personal profile. Please see pictures below.

The web add-ins are not grayed out in Outlook Web App. There they work just fine, so it looks to me like a Outlook Desktop App-only issue.

This came as a complaint from one of our customers.

[image: Calendar share invitiation]

[image: Imported/delegated calendar]

[image: Web add-ins grayed out]

Answer (score 1):

Delegate Access support for Mail/ Calendar across Outlook end points (except Mobile) is currently in preview. You can check out the documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview#delegate-access
 and give it try with the latest Outlook build.

Making the feature generally available is in progress and we hope to release soon but we cannot share a specific timeline at this stage.